# Joining reports

Tags: sql, join, statements

I am trying to join 3 reports into one, taking parts out of each report.

This is my script that works with 2 of the reports:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_JB2] AS
SELECT R.*, I.ENTERED, I.PROBLEM_CODE, I.WORKORDER
FROM DALE.DBO.V_JBTRB R
JOIN REPORTS.DBO.V_TC_ANALYSIS_JEREMY I
  ON R.HUBID = I.HUB
 AND R.NODEID = I.NODE
 AND CAST(R.CREATE_DATE AS DATE) = I.ENTERED_DATE
GO
```

and I want to add this field `A.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE  AS ASSIGN_SECS` from what should be `DALE.DBO.V_MTTA`

Comment: so i took the tour and it says it would be helpful if i showed what i had tried already. i tried adding the new item to the select statement and using join before and after the original join i also tried using a left outer and inner join command on each join statement. i figured out the first problem i was having was i was labeling the second join as reports.dbo but it isn't where that report is on the server and that was tripping me up then all my working search functions stopped working and when i googeled the error it lead me here and i tried the inner and outer joins

Comment: SELECT R.*, I.ENTERED, I.PROBLEM_CODE, I.WORKORDER,A.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE
FROM DALE.DBO.V_JBTRB R
JOIN DALE.DBO.V_MTTA
JOIN REPORTS.DBO.V_TC_ANALYSIS_JEREMY I
  ON R.HUBID = I.HUB
 AND R.NODEID = I.NODE
 AND CAST(R.CREATE_DATE AS DATE) = I.ENTERED_DATE
 AND A.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE  = ASSIGN_SECS                GIVES THIS ERROR **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure v_JB2, Line 10Incorrect syntax near 'ASSIGN_SECS'.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have anything to add to your post, edit the post (there is an "edit" button below it), don't leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your join of DALE.DBO.V_MTTA has no ON condition...
Try this:

```
SELECT R.*, I.ENTERED, I.PROBLEM_CODE, I.WORKORDER,
A.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE as ASSIGN_SECS 
FROM 
DALE.DBO.V_JBTRB R JOIN 
REPORTS.DBO.V_TC_ANALYSIS_JEREMY I 
ON R.HUBID = I.HUB AND R.NODEID = I.NODE AND 
CAST(R.CREATE_DATE AS DATE) = I.ENTERED_DATE 
JOIN DALE.DBO.V_MTTA A ON A.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE = ??? (what do you want this to be joined on? I don't know how your tables are related, but you need a valid ON statement for this join to work)
```

Comment: thanks for the assist but that also didn't work i think i somewhat understand why know though. there is nothing to match or join it with in the first or second report so i get a bound error. does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do - join that V_MTTA report so you could include the fields you want in the select but without seeing your table structure, I didn't know what you could join it on.

Comment: like i said i am really new at this using some web links and some friends to kind of teach myself. the way i was able to kind of make it make sense for me was looking at in designer mode. My bosses boss said it was beginner mode and if you get stuck look there and sometimes you see things you don't always see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

so the right answer was and i don't think anyone would have been able to tell based on the code was instead of joining a third query i added to my trb query and got the same data not sure why i didn't think of it sooner.

```
 ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_JBTRB]  AS 
    SELECT     SINGLE_USER, RECORD_ID, DIVISION, CREATE_DATETIMEINNEW,       OUTAGESTARTDATE, STATUS_DESC, CAST(HUBID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS HUBID, CAST(NODEID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS NODEID, CATEGORY, STATUS, ASSIGN_SECS
FROM         OPENQUERY(REMEDY_BI, 
                      '
 SELECT 
        T.RECORD_ID                          AS Record_ID
      , T.DIVISION                           AS Division
      , T.CREATE_DATE_ET                     AS Create_Date
      , T.TIME_IN_NEW                        AS TimeInNew
      , O.ACTUAL_START_DATE_ET               AS OutageStartDate
      , T.STATUS_DESC
      , T.FACILITY                           AS HubID
      , T.NODE                               AS NodeID
      , T.CATEGORY  
      , T.STATUS
      , T.SINGLE_USER               
      , T.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE  AS ASSIGN_SECS
 FROM ARNEUSER.VW_BASE_TROUBLE             T
 JOIN ARNEUSER.VW_BASE_OUTAGE              O
     ON O.INSTANCE_ID                        = T.OUTAGE_INSTANCE_ID
    AND O.SUBMITTED_BY                       = T.SUBMITTER
 JOIN ARNEUSER.VW_BASE_TROUBLE_TKT_ASGN_HIS A
     ON A.TROUBLE_ID                        = T.TROUBLE_ID
    AND A.CREATE_DATE                       = ( SELECT MIN(CREATE_DATE)
                                                FROM ARNEUSER.VW_BASE_TROUBLE_TKT_ASGN_HIS
                                                WHERE TROUBLE_ID=T.TROUBLE_ID
                                                  AND STATUS_NUM=1
                                                  AND CREATE_DATE>=O.ACTUAL_START_DATE
                                                  AND SUBMITTER=T.SUBMITTER )
 WHERE T.STATUS                            > 3
    AND T.REGION                              = ''Carolina''
    AND T.CREATE_DATE                        >= DATE_TO_UNIX_TZ(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-14)
    AND T.CATEGORY IN (''HFC'',''CRITICAL INFRASTRUCTURE'',''VIDEO DIGITAL'',''VIDEO ANALOG'',''DIGITAL PHONE'',''HEADEND/HUB'',''METRO/REGIONAL NETWORK'',''NATIONAL BACKBONE'',''NETWORK'')
')
```

I added this part the rest was already there if that helps this is one of the reports i was originally joining. I was trying to join another report but it came from the same data base.

```
, T.CREATE_DATE-O.ACTUAL_START_DATE  AS ASSIGN_SECS
  AND A.CREATE_DATE                       = ( SELECT MIN(CREATE_DATE)
                                                FROM ARNEUSER.VW_BASE_TROUBLE_TKT_ASGN_HIS
                                                WHERE TROUBLE_ID=T.TROUBLE_ID
                                                  AND STATUS_NUM=1
                                                  AND CREATE_DATE>=O.ACTUAL_START_DATE
                                                  AND SUBMITTER=T.SUBMITTER )
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the other query that was being joined for anyone curious the 8 **** replace some sensitive data

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_TC_ANALYSIS_JEREMY]  AS 
SELECT *, cast(entered_date + ' ' + entered_time as datetime) as ENTERED FROM OPENQUERY(ICOMS_H,'
SELECT
  W.WONUM AS WORKORDER,
  W.WOTYC AS TYPE,
  CVGDT2DATE(W.WOEDT) AS ENTERED_DATE,
  W.WOQCD AS QUEUE_CODE,
  W.WOETM AS TIME_ENTERED,
  W.WOPB1 AS PROBLEM_CODE,
  TRIM(H.HOAAEQ) AS HUB,
  TRIM(H.HONODE) AS NODE,
  H.HOZIP5 AS ZIPCODE,
  W.WOPOL AS POOL,
  P.EXTXD0 AS AREA,
  CVGTM2TIME(W.WOETM) AS ENTERED_TIME
FROM
  ********.WOMHIPF W
  JOIN ******.HOSTPF H ON H.HONUM = W.WOHNUM 
  JOIN CF83PF P ON P.EXPLLL = W.WOPOL
WHERE
  W.WOEDT >= REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 14 DAYS,ISO),''-'','''')-19000000
  AND ((WOTYC =''SR'' AND WOQCD IN (''O'',''M'')) OR (WOTYC =''TC''))

  AND WOPOL IN (''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''6'',''7'',''E'',''M'',''R'')
```